# Dynamic list covering the page... but only in Chrome for Android

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, chrome-for-android

I have a dynamically created `<ul>` list which is on this page: http://www.roadtripradar.com

(In order to view the list, you need to enter a route, add some options, and click 'Search'; the created list is under the "All Places" button under the map)

The problem that I have is that the `<ul>`, once you start scrolling, covers over everything else on the page... but only in Chrome For Android.

It work perfectly in IE, FF and Chrome on desktop. It works perfectly in Safari on iPhones.

I have tried altering the `z-values`, and it makes no difference.

The CSS I have for the list is:

```
#list {
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        -webkit-border: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 120px);
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
        width: 90wh;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        background-color: rgba(136, 169, 255, 0.5);
        display:block;
      }
```

Can anyone think what could be causing this bizarre behaviour?

I'd appreciate an extra set of eyes if you can advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out that it is a known bug in Chrome for Android (something to do with 3d rendering, which is mostly alien to me, but thankfully there are other people in the world who are more clever than me!). The upshot is that adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the `#list` fixed the problem entirely, as in:

```
#list {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        overflow: auto;
        ...
        ...
      }
```

And that's it - problem solved!

If anyone is able to explain why this works, feel free to comment.